# Why is AltGr remapped from keycode 108 to keycode 92 (LVL3) and where?

Tags: x11, xkb

While building my own xkb config file, I managed to make `AltGr` dysfunctional. Bottom line is: Removing this three lines (one is actually a whole block) ...

```
    xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes "whatever" {
            [...]
>>>>        <LVL3> = 92;
            [...]
        };
        [...]
        xkb_symbols "anything" {
            [...]
>>>>        key <LVL3> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
>>>>        modifier_map Mod5 { <LVL3> };
```

... created the problem and re-adding them made the problem disappear, now `AltGr` works as expected again. So, problem is: My keyboard doesn't have a key producing key code 92 at all (that's the reason for me to remove those lines in the first place). Now, I figured it out while running `xev` with two keyboards connected (one with system's default keyboard layout and thus working `AltGr` and the other with my broken xkb file) and playing around with the two `AltGr` keys, until I suddenly noticed this line:

```
    KeyPress event, serial 53, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
        root 0x4b1, subw 0x0, time 2986451693, (63,136), root:(716,408),
        state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
>>>>    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
        XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
        XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
        XFilterEvent returns: False
```

That was the reason for me to try re-adding those lines.

Now the question: Why is that key remapped to keycode 92 and where does that happen? (Since I didn't have any definition for that key in my file any more, my file was innocent ;)

Answer (score 1):

Today I stumpled over that, too, and I think it the reason for this that ISO_Level3_Shift is in the keycode line for keycode 92 in xmodmap's output:

```
xmodmap -pk | grep -w 92
     92         0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)       0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)
```

Or to be more precise: It maps back to the *first* keycode in the list:

```
$ xmodmap -pk | grep -i ISO_Level3_Shift
     92         0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)       0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)
    108         0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)       0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)
    134         0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)       0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xfe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift)
```